# Spliting string after certain amount of characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

I have a lengthy string and want to split it after a certain number of characters. I already have done this:

```
if len(song.lyrics) > 2048:
    string1 = string[:2048]
    string2 = string[2049:]
```

The problem with this is that sometimes it breaks in the middle of text and I don't want to. Is there a way to get the last linebreak before the character limit is reached and break it there?
Thanks

Comment: Provide a [`Minimal, Reproducible Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this give you the result you're looking for? If not, could you please provide an example string with expected output?

```py
import re
CHARACTER_LIMIT = 2048

for m in re.finditer(r'.{,%s}(?:\n|$)' % CHARACTER_LIMIT, string, re.DOTALL):
    print(m.group(0))
```

Comment: Notice that there are edge cases in which this will not return text. If a block of text has > 2048 without a newline, that block will be dropped in this scenario.

Comment: Yes it did thank you. But I would like to know how this works haha. Can you drop a link or something where this could be explained?

Comment: How refreshing for SO :) This solution is using regular expressions. You can read more about the python package here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html. The expression is searching for a a wildcard `.` for a certain number of repetitions {MINIMUM_NUMBER, MAXIMUM_NUMBER}, followed by a either a newline character `\n` or an EOF anchor `$`. The command to search for a newline or EOF is grouped in a non-capturing group: `(?:)` which just means that output isn't available in the .group() call below.

Comment: Just one last question. Using this solution it gives me a string that has nothing in it at the very final. After everything is alright I get one last empty string. Is there a way for it not to show? I've already came with a temporary solution but not elegant haha.

Comment: Yes, this is because there's no minimum match and it's able to match on the EOF anchor which is a zero-width character. You could solve this by adding a minimum match # eg: `{1, %s}` instead of `{,%s}` -- there are other ways as well, but that should give you what you want.

Comment: With that change I don't get any string at all xd

Answer (score 0):

Find the index of newline character *just-left-of* your length limit then use it to split.

```
if len(song.lyrics) > 2048:
    index = string[:2048].rfind('\n')
    string1 = string[:index]
    string2 = string[index+1:]
```

---

Example:

```
>>> s = 'aaaaaaa\nbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\nccccccc\ndddddddddddddddd'
>>> limit = 31   #                        ↑
>>> index = s[:limit].rfind('\n')
>>> index
24
>>> s1,s2 = s[:index],s[index+1:]
>>> s1
'aaaaaaa\nbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'
>>> s2
'ccccccc\ndddddddddddddddd'
>>>
```